# How can I make a common control in Objective-C that can be used in multiple views in a storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, controls, storyboard

I am just starting in my iOS development using xCode 4.2 and discovered storyboards.  They seem great for rapid prototyping.

What I'm wondering is how can I create my own custom control that I can use in multiple views.

For example, let's say I want a custom title bar that is common on every view.  I think I should be able to define that control with it's own controller and instantiate that from multiple views.  I just don't know how and the tutorials and questions I've read so far don't address this.

Any tips?

Comment: +1 because I didn't know storyboards even existed until now.

Comment: This is a fairly vague question. You might want to narrow things down and suggest what kind of control you want to create. It will largely depend on what functionality you want it to have that another control doesn't already have.

Comment: I want to make a compound control made up of the basic ones.  As an example, I want to create a custome title bar that would have something like a logo on the left, a Title on top, a sub-title underneath the title.  My thought would be that I could create my own control that looks like this that I include in several views.  That way if I decide later I want to change it, I don't need to change every view - just the one control.  I have seen a "Custom Objects" area in the Object Library but haven't found if this is what I want or how to use it yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found one way to do this is to do the following steps:

1. Create a new xib file and set the Simulated Metrics to "Freeform" to allow resizing. `(MyControl.xib)`
2. Populate the control with the Objects I want in the control.
3. Create a UIViewController for the view. `(MyViewController.h & MyViewController.m)`
4. Set the `File's Owner` of the `MyControl.xib` to the Custom Class `MyViewController`
5. In the xib that I want to include the control, I put a UIScrollView where I want the control (a regular View will work too). (`Parent.xib`)
6. Create an `IBOutlet` for the `UISCrollView` that I will put the control into in the `ParentController`.
7. Create an instance of `MyViewController` in the `ParentController`.
8. In the `ParentController`, add the view of the `MyViewController` as a subview of the `UIScrollView`.

In code, this means

```
@implementation ParentController
    @synthesize myScrollView;
    MyViewController* myController;

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {

        self = [super init];
        if(self) 
        {
            myController = [[MyController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
            [myScrollView addSubview:myController.view];
        } 
   }
```

This seems to work and allows me to separate the implementation of the Control and the Parent, but I can't help but think there is a better way.